# java refer a file inside project from runnable jar

Tags: java, file, jar, runnable, filenotfoundexception

I am writing a java swings application. In the application we need to keep a certificate file to create a custom sslContext

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
 .loadTrustMaterial(new File("certs\\cacerts"),
    "password".toCharArray(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
.build();
```

I have created the folder `“certs”` inside the project and stored the file `“cacerts”` in that folder. This is working fine, when I am running the app from eclipse. But when I am packing app as a runnable jar file, java is not getting the file, "certs\cacerts". It is throwing filenotfound exception.

But when I change the `“\\”` to `“//”` it worked fine, if I am keeping the a folder `“certs”` where the jar file is located and store the `“cacerts`” file in that. The code will be look like below,

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
 .loadTrustMaterial(new File("certs//cacerts"),
    "password".toCharArray(), new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
.build();
```

Comment: A .jar file is a single file.  Entries in a .jar are not separate files, so you cannot read them with File objects.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Apache's [`SSLContextBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html). Instead of loading trust material from a `File`, you can [load it from a `URL`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/ssl/SSLContextBuilder.html#loadTrustMaterial%28java.net.URL,%20char[],%20org.apache.http.ssl.TrustStrategy%29). And obtaining a `URL` for an in-jar file is covered in Oracle tutorial [Access to Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html).